# MySql find_in_set() not playing nice with PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Any ideas on why the following would be throwing a parameter error. I have taken a look at all the other answers on SO but I am approaching this in the same way as those solutions anyway but this still does not seem to work. Switching an app from adodb to pdo.

```
$possible_keys = implode( ",", $possible_keys_array );
```

sql snippet

```
WHERE
FIND_IN_SET(table.key,:possible_keys)

$STH = $DBH->prepare( $sql );

$STH->execute( array( $possible_keys ) );

$STH->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

I have only put in a snap shot of the code. But it all works fine if I replace the :possible_keys place-holder with the actual text of the possible_keys variable. I'm scratching my head as to why this won't work since the variable is just a string anyway. It keeps throwing the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
```

p.s. I have only included the clause that is proving to be the problem as opposed to the whole query. I know the rest of it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a named parameter but are not binding it as such. You need to specify the name:

```
$STH->execute(array(':possible_keys' => $possible_keys));
```

Comment: great I will try it out now this minute. I had missed that one. However how come it does work for all the other queries. I am using named place-holders throughout but was using normal arrays with the values in the same order to pass the data to the stmt. It seems to work fine in all the other queries why would that be? I appreciate the info thanks.

Comment: It has indeed fixed it thanks a million. Interesting though as I say above that it works for the rest but not for the find_in_set(), I can only assume it must not be safe in all cases to use the non-associative arrays thus I will make them all associative. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

1) You're using named placeholders, but you're passing a non-associative array.

If you're using question marks as placeholders, pass an array like so:

```
$STH->execute(array("a", "b", "c"))
```

If you're using named placeholders, pass an array like so:

```
$STH->execute(array("name" => "a", "name2" => "b", "name3" => "c"))
```

Edit: In my answer, I first stated that you can't place a parameter where you have one now (in the IN() statement). Apparently, that *should* work.